# Vue meta Alpha8 doens't generate meta tags properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi I'm using Vue3 with `vue-meta: ^3.0.0-alpha.8`. I'm trying to setup my project in order to set dynamically the meta-tags.
Here my code on `App.vue`:

```
import constants from './constants'

export default {
   data() {
      return {
         constants: constants
         }
      }
   },
   setup() {
      useMeta({
         htmlAttrs: { 
            lang: constants.meta.language,
         },
         description: constants.main.description,
         meta: [
            {
               name: 'author',
               content: constants.meta.author
            },
            {
               name: 'keywords',
               content: constants.meta.keywords
            },
            {
               name: 'robots',
               content: constants.meta.robots
            }
          ]
      }
   }
}
```

`htmlAttrs` and `description` works fine generating: `<html lang="en" ...`  and `<meta name="description" content="My description">`

The other tags, on the other hand, are generated incorrectly:

```
<meta name="meta" content="my author string">
<meta name="meta" content="my keywords string">
<meta name="meta" content="my robots string">
```

Why it is generating `<meta name="meta" ..` instead of `<meta name="MY PARAMETER NAME" ..`?
I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same issue, I looked into the vue-meta files and found that you can add your own config to the createMetaManager function like so in your main.js file:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { createMetaManager } from "vue-meta";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
// import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
// import config from "./aws-exports";

import "./assets/css/tailwind.css";

createApp(App)
.use(store)
.use(router)
.use(
    createMetaManager(false, {
    body: {
        tag: "script",
        to: "body",
    },
    base: {
        valueAttribute: "href",
    },
    charset: {
        tag: "meta",
        nameless: true,
        valueAttribute: "charset",
    },
    description: {
        tag: "meta",
    },
    og: {
        group: true,
        namespacedAttribute: true,
        tag: "meta",
        keyAttribute: "property",
    },
    twitter: {
        group: true,
        namespacedAttribute: true,
        tag: "meta",
    },
    htmlAttrs: {
        attributesFor: "html",
    },
    headAttrs: {
        attributesFor: "head",
    },
    bodyAttrs: {
        attributesFor: "body",
    },
    robots: {
        tag: "meta",
    },
    })
)
.mount("#app");
```

The first argument in createMetaManager is isSSR, the second is the config (there's a defaultConfig variable inside vue-meta/dist/vue-meta.csj.js that I copied then modified to include a robots object). This is my home route:

```
<script>
import { useMeta } from "vue-meta";

export default {
  name: "HomePage",
  setup() {
    useMeta({
      title: "title",
      htmlAttrs: { lang: "en", amp: true },
      description: "desc",
      robots: "index, follow",
    });
  },
};
</script>
```